# jquery Curvy Corner plugin doesn't load after JSF ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, curvycorners

We are using Curvy corners script (http://www.curvycorners.net) for the JSF buttons to have the curvy corners in IE.

In IE when we make a Ajax call ,in Ajax response this curvy corners doesn't executed so we tried to re-execute the curvy corner script .  as below in JSF ,but still the curvy corner is not refreshed ,how to reload the curvy corner in Ajax response

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent( function(data) {
if (data.status == "success") { // Can be 'begin', 'complete' and 'success'.
alert("curvy corner");
 var settings = {
 tl: { radius: 5 }, tr: { radius: 5 }, bl: { radius: 5 }, br: { radius: 5 },        antiAlias: true
    };
    $.getScript("jquery.curvycorners.min.js", function() {
    curvyCorners(settings, '.button-primary'); });

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the callback method of `$.getScript()` is invoked? It won't be invoked if the location of the script file is invalid. Are you sure that the `$.getScript()` call is necessary? It's not necessary if the script is already loaded by the page itself in the `<head>`.

Comment: BaluCs ...$.getScript() is not invoked. How else to  reload the script? because in Ajax reload....curvy corners are not getting called

Comment: If that is not invoked, then `alert("curvy corner")` should also not be invoked at all. Is this true? You are not very clear in describing the concrete problem. Please elaborate in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. Do you for instance see any JS errors/warnings in the JS console? Is the whole `addOnEvent` function actually invoked? Etc. Run the JS debugger.

Comment: Possibly off-topic: looks like you're missing an end-curly-brace.

Comment: alert("cury corner") is invoked...but .getScript is not loading curvycorner script

Comment: Well, go back to my 1st comment.

Comment: there is no syntax....might be a typo in my question

Comment: The problem is ....as the curvy corner is loaded in <head> so only button looks curvy on page load , but after ajax ....button looses the curve...it is only in IE

Comment: As said in my 1st comment, the `$.getScript()` location is likely invalid. But you don't need `$.getScript()` at all if you have it already in the `<head>`. Just invoke `curvyCorners()` directly. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> *.getScript is not loading curvycorner script*

Then the location which you specified in `$.getScript()` is just invalid. As you have specified it now (without a leading slash), it's relative to the current request URL. Imagine that you have opened the JSF page by http://localhost:8080/context/some/folder/some.xhtml, then the `$.getScript("jquery.curvycorners.min.js")` will try to load it from http://localhost:8080/context/some/folder/jquery.curvycorners.min.js. Your problem indicates that the file is actually not there at all, but on a different folder or something.

The callback function of  `$.getScript()` is only called when the script is successfully loaded. So you need to fix the location accordingly so that it get loaded properly.

But as you mentioned in the comments, you have this script already in the `<head>` and it is already working on page load. You don't need to load the whole script again by `$.getScript()` at all. Just invoke the callback function directly.

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") {
        var settings = {
            tl: { radius: 5 }, tr: { radius: 5 }, bl: { radius: 5 }, br: { radius: 5 },        antiAlias: true
        };
        curvyCorners(settings, '.button-primary');
    }
}
```

Comment: $.getScript() was the problem ...location was wrong,i corrected the location to "/common/js/jquery.curvycorners.min.js" ,then it worked fine.... in this we had to reload the script to fix all the curvy corners in IE

Comment: BaluCs ,one thing we observerd is jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data), is called only on the first Ajax request on the same view ,if we do subsequent ajax request ,this doesn't call the jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(